# Using TOR with python on windows - Cannot find installer

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tor, stem

I am trying to learn how to use Python with TOR. However, I cannot find anywhere TOR client for windows (equivilent to "apt-get install tor" on linux, or ORbot on android).

All I find is the TOR browser, which I already have and use. I am using stem with Python to connect to TOR, but as I have nothing installed it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/8bitb/Desktop/Python Stuff/tor.py", line 19, in <module>
    init_msg_handler=print_bootstrap_lines,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\stem\process.py", line 273, in launch_tor_with_config
    return launch_tor(tor_cmd, args, torrc_path, completion_percent, init_msg_handler, timeout, take_ownership)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\stem\process.py", line 86, in launch_tor
    raise OSError("'%s' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH?" % tor_cmd)
OSError: 'tor' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH?
```

I cannot find a simple install anywhere. I expect I am missing something obvious. Please may someone rectify my stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the torbrowser as usual, it has the Tor network built in. You can get the expert bundle if you really want configuration options.

You then need to add the tor command line executables (whatever directory you used to install torbrowser to) to your windows path which will let you invoke tor?

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Alternatively, just proxy through tor once you start it up?

Comment: Are you referring to the tor.exe etc in the tor browser directory?

Comment: Yep.... Tor browser is a wrapper that starts up firefox and tor.exe and then sets up the proxy settings so you can connect.